# Ghidra: What are "hash" function variables in the listing view

Tags: ghidra

The variables at the bottom prefixed with `HASH:xxxxx:8`, what are these variables and why are they here?

[image]

When I delete them Ghidra insists on re-adding them when I `Commit local names` so I'm guessing they must be of some importance or Ghidra is detecting they exist in some way.